# Change UIControlEvent of UIAlertController to TouchDown?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm looking to change the UIControl event of my button on my UIAlertController to activate on Touch-down. To do this, I need to change the UIControlEvent to touch-down.

There are a few ways of doing this that I can think of...

1. Somehow gain access to the UIAlertAction's UIControlEvent and set it
   to touch-down
2. Gain access to the UIAlertController's buttons and add a target which I can then easily set the UIControlEvent
3. Subclass the UIAlertController and override the touchesBegan method

Does anyone know how to implement either of the first 2 methods?